# How to write a function to pass 2 tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, tdd

I am learning and practicing writing test with javascript:

Here is the test cases `find.test.js`:

```
var findTheNeedle = require("./find-needle");

test("Find the needle", function () {
  var words = ["house", "train", "slide", "needle", "book"];
  var expected = 3;

  var output = findTheNeedle(words, "needle");

  expect(output).toEqual(expected);
});

test("Find the plant", function () {
  var words = ["plant", "shelf", "arrow", "bird"];
  var expected = 0;

  var output = findTheNeedle(words, "plant");

  expect(output).toEqual(expected);
});
```

Here is my following function `find.js`:

```
function findNeedle(words) {
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (words[i] === "needle") {
      var needle = i;
    }
  }

  return needle;
}
module.exports = findNeedle;
```

Comment: `function findNeedle(words, word) { return words.indexOf(word); }`

Comment: @hoangdv - the OP might be more likely to see it if you move it to an answer :) Nicely done.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this:

```
var findTheNeedle = require("./find-needle");

test("Find the object", function () {
  var words = ["house", "train", "slide", "needle", "book"];
  var expected = 3;

  var output = findTheNeedle(words, "needle");

  expect(output).toEqual(expected);

  var words = ["plant", "shelf", "arrow", "bird"];
  var expected = 0;

  var output = findTheNeedle(words, "plant");

  expect(output).toEqual(expected);
});
```

Bit I think you need to remake the function, like this:

```
function findInArray( arr, word ) {
  let index = -1
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === word) {
       index = i;
    }
  }

  return index;
}
module.exports = findInArray;
```

If any of "expects" fails, all the test will fail

Answer (score 0):

It seems your function will return the index of a "word" in a list of words. This means, your function has to receive 2 variables as parameters: "word" and "words".

I think the current function name (and filename) - `findNeedle` is not "correct", so I recommended changing it. How about `findWordIndex`?

The function logic is simple, you can use `Array.indexOf` utility to do it, or do it in your way.

```
module.exports = (words, word) => words.indexOf(word);
```

Or

```
module.exports = (words, word) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (words[i] === word) {
      return i; // stop right after you found it
    }
  }
  return -1;
};
```